# OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated - what does it really mean?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am trying to fit a curve/function to a set of 2D points (x,y).

I am using `sp.optimize.curve_fit` for that purpose.

I am trying to fit this objective function to my data.

```
def objective_f(x, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, c):
    s1 = np.log(x+1.0)
    s2 = (x+1.0)
    s3 = np.log(x+1.0) * (x+1.0)
    s4 = (x+1.0)*(x+1.0)
    s5 = np.exp ( (x+1.0) / 1e8 )

    return a1 * s1 + a2 * s2 + a3 * s3 + a4 * s4 + a5 * s5 + b1 / s1 + b2 / s2 + b3 / s3 + b4 / s4 + b5 / s5 + c
```

I do it by just this simple call:

`popt, _ = sp.optimize.curve_fit(objective_f, x, y)`

Here `x` and `y` are just taken from 2 columns of an existing pandas `DataFrame` as follows:

`x = df2['population'].astype('float64').values`
`y = df2['budget'].astype('float64').values`

The parameters I get back seem to be fine and to estimate the given data quite well.

But I keep getting this warning

`minpack.py:829: OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated category=OptimizeWarning)`

I googled for it and I found a couple of pages but none of them seems to explain well what this is about.

***Why am I getting this warning?***

***Is this warning something I should be worried about?***

Comment: can you provide the data, x, y?

Comment: note that terms in your objective function can go to infinity (e.g. `log(0)`).  This is likely the source.

Comment: ...and the term 1/x.  If you added some epsilon values, e.g. s1 -> `eps + np.log(x+1.0)` so this will not go to zero, this warning will likely go away.

Comment: My Xs are integers >= 30000 and <= 4 million so they cannot go to 0, even if they could, I am adding 1 there before taking log. But it's possible that I have multiple Ys for a single X. Could that be the reason?